# With OpenSceneGraph, how do I make it use GL_REPLACE to render my texture?

Tags: openscenegraph

With OpenSceneGraph, how do I make it use `GL_REPLACE` to render my texture?
I do not want the color of my texture to change with orientation.
I also want the rendered color to match the values of the texture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Geode that contains the texture (and probably any node above it, as long as you don't override it), you can do this:

```
osg::TexEnv* pTexEnv = new osg::TexEnv();
pTexEnv->setMode(osg::TexEnv::REPLACE);
pGeode->getOrCreateStateSet()->setTextureAttributeAndModes(0, pTexEnv, osg::StateAttribute::ON);
```

Now the texture will be drawn with exactly it's own color.